# Getting User data from facebook registration plugin and storing it in my database

Tags: facebook

I want get data from facebook through the registration plugin and store it my database with php to keep track of the users who sign in with facebook. How can i do that. Documentation does clarify on this. Any ideas or examples of how it can be implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wasswa,

Please take a look at the [Registration Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/) documentation, search the page for 'Reading the data'. Essentially, once the user has submitted their information facebook will pass the information to your page in the signed_request param which can only be decoded by your application secret. The php sdk helps with decoding the signed requests, doc [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getSignedRequest/)